# How to solve Sign in with Facebook after deploy to Heroku?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I built a website and i worked on my localhost , after i deployed my project to Heroku i cant access login with facebook from mobile phones.

I gen an error:
“Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.“

This is my project:
https://fierce-escarpment-77863.herokuapp.com/

[image: My facebook dev app settings]
I dont have any idea how can i solve this

Comment: So what _do_ you have in the App Domains field? Your screenshot does not show that.

Comment: where can i find my App Domains field?

Comment: Settings -> Basic